# Saber ModelState no javascript dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em ASP.NET MVC 5 e estou com um problema em colocar um modal de carregamento enquanto o formulario é salvo, pois quando há algo invalido no formulario o javascript não respeita, mostrando o modal de carregamento, gostaria de saber como pegar o ModelState dinamico para liberar o modal somente quando o estiver true, assim evitando mostrar o modal equivocadamente.

Estou tentando usar dessa forma sem sucesso:

```
$('#salvar').click(function () {
            var isValid = ${ViewData.ModelState.IsValid};
            if (!isValid) {
                waitingDialog.hide();
            } else {
                waitingDialog.show('Salvando Chamado...');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Quais plug-ins você está utilizando para validação do formulário no front-end? Unobtrusive JQuery?

Comment: @Vinícius, Estou usando o padrão do ASP.NET MVC 5 MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você tem que entender que a impressão do código da sua *View* (`Html`, `css`, `javascript`...) e a renderização do código `Razor` (Que é um *View Engine* no `ASP.NET`) é feito no momento em que a requisição da sua página é aceita pelo servidor, desse modo, fazendo com que mais nada codificado em `Razor` seja interpretado novamente naquela *View*.

Quando realizar qualquer requisição `Ajax` tentando passar um valor renderizado pelo `Razor` já foi impresso lá no inicio da renderização do código.

Segue o exemplo:

Código `html` com o `Razor`:

```
@{
  ViewBag.StringTeste = "Renderizou!";
}

<script>
  function ImprimeValorRazor() {
      var stringExemple = '@ViewBag.StringTeste';
      alert(stringExemple);
  };
</script>
```

Código renderizado:

```
<script>
  function ImprimeValorRazor() {
      var stringExemple = 'Renderizou!';
      alert(stringExemple);
  };
</script>
```

Esse controle do `ModelState` é melhor controlado pela sua aplicação e não pela sua View, pois se o usuário alterar o código através do navegador vai conseguir causar exceções diretamente na sua aplicação até mesmo pulando suas validações.

Faça ele mostrar uma mensagem pro usuário com as validações que não passaram no retorno da sua requisição ou então use os *Data Notations* diretamente na entidade para a validação automática.